# what is the inverse of this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse, cubics

I'm weak at math and I need the inverse of this function if it's computable:

$f(t) = A + (-2t^3 + 3t^2)(B-A)$

Note that $A$ and $B$ are constants.

thanks for your help.

Comment: The function has three possible inverses if $f(t)$ is between $A$ and $B$.  One inverse between 0 and 1, one below 0, one above 1.   There is only one inverse if $f(t)$ is outside the interval from $A$ to $B$.  What values of $f(t)$ are you interested in?

Comment: This is (for $A\neq B$) a cubic polynomial $-2(B-A)t^3+3(B-A)t^2+A-f=0$. You can find the formulas to find $t$ as a function of $A,B,f$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cardano-Tartaglia want you to find the cube root of a complex number.  (whenever there are three real roots, the cube-root is of a complex number.)
Another option is Newton's Method.  Let $$g(t)=6(t-t^2)(B-A)$$
You should run this up to $t_3$ or $t_4$, or until $t$ doesn't change much:

$t_1=1/2\\
t_2=t_1-(f(t_1)/g(t_1))\\
t_3=t_2-(f(t_2)/g(t_2))\\
t_4=t_3-(f(t_3)/g(t_3))$

Comment: thanks for your clear answer